# Why is my Parallel Code Running Slow?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, timing

I have been asked to use ForkJoin to write the following method:

```
public static boolean hasOver(int val, int[] arr, int sequentialCutoff)
```

and my code must have a work of O(n), a span of O(lgn) and use the sequentialCutoff argument. I figured this problem would be fairly straight forward and one in which sequentialCutoff would set the threshold, and the recursion would occur over half the array, repeating until hitting the threshold, before hitting the base case which would just traverse the array over the specified indices, checking to see if any elements greater than val exist. Here is the parallel code portion of what I wrote:

```
protected Boolean compute() {
    if(high - lo <= sequentialCutoff) {
        return sequentialCheckHasOver(check, array);
    } else {
        int mid = lo + (high - lo) / 2;
        CheckHasOver left = new CheckHasOver(check, array, lo, mid, cutoff);
        left.fork();
        CheckHasOver right = new CheckHasOver(check, array, mid, high, cutoff);
        return right.compute() || left.join();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I now run timing tests on the code that I wrote, no matter what threshold I choose, the sequential code is running faster than my parallel code and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out where my reasoning has failed. Can anyone see a mistake in what I've done? Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A guess: you spawn too many threads! Creating a thread, destroying the handle and context switches cost time. The computation is very cheap, so your try to parallelize is just overhead with barely an advantage.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Would you say the error is in my implementation of the recursion? I had assumed that splitting the array in half with each fork would give me a span of O(lg n), was I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: Your fault is to use threads in a recursion. Every thread has not enough to do to be worth and because they're so many, most of them share a core, so they're just a slowdown. Splitting just the first pass of `compute` in 2 threads may be an advantage when both forks have something to do.